# Popup homepage when website load?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, popup

**edited/updated**   I need to open this popup when visit home page only..

I tried javascript but doesn't work here..

```
if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){
 $( window ).load(function() {
     openFeedbackWindow('feedback_information')

    });
}
```

I tried more .. like

```
window.location.href
```

and php code also in `footer.phtml` where I load this block..

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=='mywebsiteurl'); ){
load block... 
}
```

window.location

I need to open this popup when website load now it's open by click on left sidebar button.

[image]

here is my code where this popup is triggered..

```
 <div class="side-feedback">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openFeedbackWindow('feedback_information')" title="Feedback" id="link_feedback"></a> 
    </div>
```

I try this..

```
  $( window ).load(function() {
     openFeedbackWindow('feedback_information')

    });
```

Comment: Normally you would do this by calling the function that displays the popup with a `setTimeout()` after the page loads or something. Could you explain a little what you've tried or what your set up is?

Comment: @bassplayer7 I try this.. ( update my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code it will click your sidebar and popup will load

```
jQuery( window ).load(function() {
   jQuery('.cms-index-index .side-feedback a').get(0).click();
});
```

Comment: need to load homepage only..

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: what is class in body in home page please check and let me know

Comment: cms-index-index cms-homepage1 offcanvas-container layout-fullwidth fs

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Can i get the resource to develop feedback form same what shown above https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUQyQ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the JavaScript snippet below into the content of your CMS homepage...

```
<script>
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            openFeedbackWindow('feedback_information');
        }, 3000); // 3 seconds
    });
</script>
```

A better way would be to create a template using the above snippet then render it in the `cms_index_index` layout handle. This method should reduce the risk of content editors breaking the JS.